# Write KV Pcollection to Pubsub using PubsubIO.writeAvros()

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

I have a PCollection of type <KV<String, MyCustomClass>>.
The key represents the topic ID of the pubsub topic where the value must be published. How can I achieve this using PubsubIO.writeAvros(MyCustomClass) method?

I tried checking out the documentation but couldn't find anything really relevant.

Also is there a way to format the output using something like withFormatFunction() like we have for BigQueryIO? I need this so that I can pass only the value and not the entire KV to PubsubIO.

Thanks.